# How is CCD data converted to frames in practice?

Tags: data-acquisition, ccd

After reading [this](https://hamamatsu.magnet.fsu.edu/articles/digitalimagebasics.html) article I noticed that one can sample CCD by an ADC and convert the signal waveform to image since each pixel's color is function of ADC sample.

Lets say we can sample this CCD signal in real time and plot it in our computer as:

[image]

What is the efficient way used in to convert this data to image in practice in SW side(I'm more interested in grayscale)? I know how to manipulate pixels in C# using Bitmap. So I was thinking to convert ADC samples to pixel data using Bitmap in WinForms in C# for instance.

But I have no experience with CCD data processing so I might be in wrong direction. I would appreciate anyone's answer with some experience with that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a GPU, no processing at all is required. You can pass the GPU a pointer to the buffer, give it the pixel format and image dimensions, and the hardware will render the image for you. Which should not be surprising, a 2D bitmap is actually a 1D array of numbers in memory, so the hardware is perfectly happy to leave it that way in memory.

The actual read out is more complex then you're thinking though, since you need additional signals from the sensor to tell you where the frame starts. Typically there is at least a frame trigger from the sensor to tell you when a frame begins/ends. There may also be a line trigger to tell you when read out of a line of pixels is complete, although this isn't always required if you know the sensor pixel configuration.

Comment: 1) So you suggest something using GPU, like OPENGL? 2) Does frame trigger fires each time a frame is sent from the UART of CCD? Thanks

Comment: For efficient video playback using the GPU is a good idea, especially at higher resolution or frame rates. The frame trigger (also called frame sync) will be described in the datasheet, but somehow indicates when a frame starts (or ends) so that you know which pixel is the first pixel. Otherwise you would start at a random pixel in the middle of the frame.

Comment: Here is a sample .NET application that takes raw sensor data and renders it to the screen (with or without additional processing) using opengl: https://github.com/mgiacomelli/VirtualHE

Comment: @GNZ I have seen vendor-supplied software that simply copied pixels into a .NET Bitmap. You can do this at lower pixel rates, but eventually you become CPU limited. On an old Haswell Xeon, ~30 MP/s (roughly 720p TV) was ok but occasionally stuttered. If you have a new 200 MP/s camera, probably you need something like the example code I linked above. At 10 MP/s, it won't matter.

Comment: Thank you. I just want to avoid C++ and/or OpenGL route since I know C#. But I have a question. Wouldnt averaging frames or skipping them help when copying pixels to .Net Bitmap for higher MP/s? For real time view I mean?

Comment: @GNZ The example code is .NET so you can use c#. If your code is too slow to run at full frame rate then you will skip frames.

Comment: The code is written in C++

Comment: @GNZ I think you may not understand what that example is showing. It is a .net library (written in c#) for rendering using opengl. Since it is a .NET library you can use it in c# (which I have done and works great). The GUI code (which does not matter to you) is written in c++ .NET.  Hopefully that makes sense to you, if not consider asking about .net programming on stack overflow.

Comment: Oh okay I got it. I will try thanks. And if you have simple example application u can share would be amazing otherwise thanks a lot. I will try to integrate it WinForms or WPF using C#.

Comment: I found this trying to get into it. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138452/An-Analog-Clock-Design-Using-OpenTK-in-Csharp

Answer (score 1):

If you're not even doing color, what you read from the CCD *is* image data. The only thing you might need to do is apply [gamma correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction); the values you read from the CCD should be more-or-less linear (twice the light intensity = twice the voltage), while displays and most image file formats expect gamma-encoded data (brightness is mapped to digital values in a nonlinear way that corresponds to human perception of brightness, which makes more efficient use of bits).

But whether or not you need to do that is dependent on application; if you're passing the data to some kind of a scientific imaging library, it might already be expecting linear data, or have a flag that lets you tell it that the data is linear

Comment: I was mostly worried about performance in SW side